# Alternative to PhoneReg.exe

Tags: windows, windows-phone

Is there an alternative way to register your device in your Developer account?
I have so much problems with using the normal way, that is PhoneReg.exe. First of all, after downloading many, many different versions of the Windows Phone SDK and trying them all, I don't even have the PhoneReg.exe executable itself, which means I had to download it from a site. I downloaded the PhoneReg.exe and the DLL which comes with it. And with that I cannot register my device, it keeps saying that it couldn't connect. I have a Lumia 930.

I've tried everything. Restrting the service, another USB cable, port, computer, it just doesn't work.

So thats why Im asking here, is there a more simple alternative for this? I really don't understand why even Apple, who has a lot more complicated way of using devices with profiles, etc. etc. is getting the job better done. Microsoft is really slacking, and with these kind of problems, I'm really hesitant to support the platform, no wonder all these developers are not even bothering with the platform if it doesn't work.

Comment: If you have windows 10 mobile on the phone there is an option in settings to enable debugging.  For windows phone 8.1 Is the phone connected to the internet via wifi or phone data plan?  Is the date time right on the phone?

Comment: I have a Windows 8.1 phone unfortunately. I've tried everything, working via Wi-Fi over 4G, setting date not automatic, every tip and trick out there on the internet, I tried it. I've spend almost 6-7 hours getting to work this thing. Should I just go for Windows 10 or isn't that a good idea?